# ini_set is NOT setting the values inside php.ini

Tags: php, server, ini, ini-set

I'm trying to set a new directory for `upload_tmp_dir` and set a new `upload_max_filesize` but it's not working... I'm displaying the results but I'm getting the old (default php.ini settings) back...

```
ini_set('upload_tmp_dir','/');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','1024M');
```

And now let's display the results :

```
echo 'Your Temp Upload Directory : '.ini_get('upload_tmp_dir').'<br>';
echo 'Your Upload Max Filesize : '.ini_get('upload_max_filesize').'<br>';
```

The original php.ini default settings is displayed to the screen and not my new settings.

What could possibly be the reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all php.ini values can be overriden by `php_ini()` function. Full list could be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php).
And changable values could be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php).

Basicly You cannt override these two values in php file.

`upload_tmp_dir` can be set only in php.ini file and `upload_max_filesize` can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini files.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set all parameters with ini_set()!

Take a look into [the appedix-list](http://php.net/manual/de/ini.list.php) there you can see which params could be set in wich version in which type